# EF Core 3.1 context being disposed after first use

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue where while looping through a data set and looking in the db to see if it already exists, it works the first run but the second item causes an error.

The following method builds up a List from a raw data file

```
private async Task<List<Vehicle>> CreateListOfVehiclesFromAuctionDataFile(IEnumerable<string> rows)
    {           
        var cars = new List<Vehicle>();
        var vinList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var dataRow in rows)
        {
            var data = dataRow.Split(",");
            var dto = GetCarModelInfoFromAuctionData(dataRow);
            if (vinList.Contains(data[14]))
            {
                continue;
            }
            vinList.Add(data[14]);
           
            var car = new Vehicle
            {
                Vin = data[14],
                InteriorColor = data[15],
                ExteriorColor = data[16],
                VehicleImageUrl = data[17],
                Notes = data[18],
                ModelId = await GetModelIdFromCarModelDto(dto)
            };                
            cars.Add(car);
        }           
        return cars;
    }
```

That method calls this method within it

```
private async Task<int> GetModelIdFromCarModelDto(CarModelDto dto)
    {
        var modelId =0;
        try
        {
            modelId = await _context.Models.Where(u => u.ModelYear == dto.ModelYear)
                        .Where(u => u.ModelType == dto.ModelType)
                        .Where(u => u.BodyStyle.Contains(dto.BodyStyle))
                        .Select(u => u.ModelId)
                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();                            
             
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error here
            var errorMessage = $"Model id not found: {ex.Message}- Exception: {ex.InnerException}";
        }
        return modelId;           
    }
```

Those private method calls come from this public method

```
public async Task<int> AddVehicleDataFromAuctionFileAsync()
    {
        var currentRecords = _context.AuctionDatum.Count();
        var data = await AzureDataRetrieval.GetDataAsStreamAsync(AzureService.AzureContainer,
            AzureFilePathsFromMain.VehicleAuctionData);
        var rows = ConvertAuctionDataStreamToDataArray(data);

        **var cars = await CreateListOfVehiclesFromAuctionDataFile(rows);**
        var datum = CreateListOfVehicleAuctionData(rows);
        await _context.AuctionDatum.AddRangeAsync(datum);
        await _context.Vehicles.AddRangeAsync(cars);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return await _context.AuctionDatum.CountAsync() - currentRecords;
    }
```

The main method call comes from the controller

```
public VehiclesController(CarCollectionDataContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {
        var vm = new VehicleDataViewModel(VehicleView.Models);
        var mgr = new VehicleDataManager(_context, _configuration);
        **var datum = mgr.AddVehicleDataFromAuctionFileAsync();**
       
        vm.Models = await mgr.GetModelListAsync();
        return View(vm);
    }
```

The first time through this method it works fine and retrieve's the ModelId. The second time through it fails with the following error message. The where clause parameters, when checked manually, show there is an item that should be retrieved.

> Model id not found: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection
> and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context,
> or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of
> disposing context instances.
> Object name: 'CarCollectionDataContext'.- Exception:

I am not disposing the context anywhere in the code. The context IS brought in via DI

```
  private readonly CarCollectionDataContext _context;
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;        

    public VehicleDataManager(CarCollectionDataContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _context = context;
        _configuration = configuration;
        AzureService = new AzureService.AzureService(_configuration);
    }
```

I am at the end of my knowledge base on how to resolve this, any help appreciated.

Comment: My guess is try registering it as `Singleton`

Comment: You are only showing us two private methods. How are you calling CreateListOfVehiclesFromAuctionDataFile? Are you missing an `await` somewhere up there that could cause the method to exit and the scope to be disposed?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Added the main calling method in the OP

Comment: Show how you set up your dependency injection.

Comment: @CodeCaster...just the standard services.AddDbContext<CarCollectionDataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connString));

Comment: Don't add characters after a username, or the notification won't work. And how do you register `VehicleDataManager`?

Comment: @CodeCaster and therein lies the problem, I had the DI call for that commented out

Comment: I think @Karl-JohanSjögren is right. 
Try calling : `var datum = await mgr.AddVehicleDataFromAuctionFileAsync();`
with `await`